# PHP target specific YAML document inside same YAML file

Tags: php, yaml

In PHP, when working with YAML, is it possible to work with a specific document inside of the yaml file?

Eg

```
--- #settings
Settings go here
...

--- #user
Users go here
...
```

Is it possible to load only users into php so I can work only with that documents data?

Comment: Do you want the second document, or the one that is commented with "user"? Because for documents identified by their position, simply use the `$pos` argument with the builtin parsers. But, afaik, they don't fetch the comments, so you'd need external parsers to select by the appearance of certain comments.

Comment: @pmf The one that's commented as user...

Comment: That's a pity. I'll use pos then.

Comment: Wow, I honestly didn't know that YAML supported multiple documents. I think if I ever encountered it in the wild I would have assumed it was invalid YAML to begin with.

Comment: If you're not using any tags or directives, then using the `---` and `...` separators only adds needless complexity to the document.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. As noted in some comments, some popular libraries do not support this (Symfony YAML does not). But if you have the php YAML extension, the document number is just an additional paramenter of `yaml_parse`. Pass `pos` 1 to load only the second document in your example.

From [the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse.php):

> ```
>  yaml_parse(
>     string $input,
>     int $pos = 0,
>     int &$ndocs = ?,
>     array $callbacks = null ): mixed
> ```

where:

> **pos**
>
> Document to extract from stream (-1 for all documents, 0 for first document, ...).

Answer (score -1):

use Symfony YAML Component or Spyc

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Load the autoload from Symfony YAML Component

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

// YAML file path
$file = 'path/to/your/file.yaml';

// Load the entire YAML file
$data = Yaml::parseFile($file);

// Access the data for the 'user' section
$usersData = $data['user'];

// Now you can work with $usersData
// ...
?>
```

Comment: When I run your code against the provided YAML I get "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string". According to the Symfony documentation, I don't think they support document structures.

Comment: This is [not supported](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11840).